# Force Fresh Network Request And response using okhttp 2.5.0

Tags: android, okhttp

I am calling a webservice from an android application from which i need to fetch a certain number of records per call (20)...the issue is that i am stuck with getting the first 20 records because for whatever reason okhttp does not serve me the next batch after i have completed processing the first 20.

I want to disable caching and force a fresh network call for each request, but the code i researched

```
request.setCacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK);
```

Only works on higher versions of okhttp and i am using version 2.5.x

A snippet of code for my request is this:

```
 Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .build();
```

how can i force a fresh network call on each request?...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More research uncovered this as the answer:

```
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                    .build();
```